# how to correctly multiply 2 matrix?

Tags: matlab

I do the 3 following operations

```
 A = (1:7)
 B = sqrt(2*pi.*A)
 C = (A./exp(1)).^(A)
```

which returns

```
A =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7

B =
    2.5066    3.5449    4.3416    5.0133    5.6050    6.1400    6.6319

C =
    0.3679    0.5413    1.3443    4.6888   21.0561  115.6487  750.9740
```

I then do

```
 returnVal = B.*C
```

which I would expect to be the multiplication of first cell from B with first cell from C, etc... But instead I get those weird values

```
returnVal =
   1.0e+03 *
    0.0009    0.0019    0.0058    0.0235    0.1180    0.7101    4.9804
```

What is happening?

Comment: The .* operator is an element-wise multiplication.  This means what you did was B(1) * C(1), and so on.  Your numbers are correct for the command you typed in.  What did you want?

Comment: Try typing `format long g` which will print in long format.  Maybe the scientific notation is messing with you.

Comment: exactly this if I understand correctly... but B(1)*C(1) doesn't equal 1.0e+3*0,0009 (It's smaller than 1). Except if I don't get something?

Comment: 1.0e3 * 0.0009 --> 1000*0.0009 --> 0.9 ?

Comment: 0.0009 * 1.0e3 is 0.9....again I don't understand your problem....

Comment: I did format long and when I print returnVal I get for the first one : 0.000922137008896

Comment: aa no wait you are right.... there is still a 1.0*e. Is there a way to just have the normal value?

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim - Check the duplicate.  Also, this code run in IDEOne may be useful.  Lesson is, use `format long g`: http://ideone.com/Pro0bp

Comment: thanks!! I'm glad it's not a coding error. Need to read more about those formats.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim - Yup... there's nothing wrong with the data... just different **representations** of the number.  `format long g` is a format I find useful.